# How to actually recognize a number using already taught model?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I've went through tensorflowjs guide on recognizing handwritten digits for node, and in the end I've got a folder with two files: model.json, weights.bin.
Now I want to use this model to recognize a number on an image.

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const path = require('path');
const jimp = require('jimp');

async function loadModel() {
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(`file://${path.resolve('./model/model.json')}`); // load model
  jimp.read('img0.png').then(img => { // load image with white background and black handwritten number
    img.resize(28, 28).greyscale().invert(); // resize the image and make background black and the number itself white
    console.log(img.bitmap.data.length);
    const buffer = img.bitmap.data.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => { // removing gba bytes so we have only value of r, which is a number in range 0-255
      if (idx % 4 === 0) {
        acc.push(curr);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
    console.log(buffer.length); // now we have 28x28 bytes
    const imageShape = [buffer.length, 28, 28, 1]; // I have no idea
    const image = new Float32Array(tf.util.sizeFromShape(imageShape)); // what
    image.set(buffer); // I'm 
    const prediction = model.execute(tf.tensor4d(image, imageShape)); // doing 
    console.log(prediction); // here
  });
}
loadModel();
```

So I have a buffer of 784 bytes that corresponds to 784 values of pixels of an image and I want to get a prediction in a form of a single number, but I don't know how to do it.

UPDATE: I've used `predict` instead of `execute` and then called `print()` and it gave me a result!

Answer (score 0):

To use your model for inference, the tensor needs to be of shape [28,28,1] for a single image. But since model predict takes a batches of image, the tensor to pass it to your predict function should be of shape [b, 28,28,1] where b is the number of images whose number is to be predicted. 
Also consider using `predict` instead of `execute`.

Here is a change:

```
const image = new Float32Array(28*28*1);
image.set(buffer); 
const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor4d(image, [1, 28, 28, 1]))
```

Comment: now it says Error: Cannot find SymbolicTensors for output name(s): [null]. I guess I have to pass those symbolic tensors as the second parameter of execute, in a form of an array of strings, or just a single string, but which values should I use? I tried "accuracy" but it didn't help to get results.

Comment: yeah but it didn't help me much since I've figured it out by the time